# Что означает список[срез, число] запись списка в Python?

Tags: python, список, numpy, keras

Разбираюсь с нейронными сетями на Keras в Python. Уже видел несколько примеров, где исходный набор данных dataset обрабатывают при помощи кода следующего вида:

```
for i in range(n):
    a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
    dataX.append(a)
    dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)
```

То есть `список[срез, число]` - `dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]`. 
Или бывает так - `dataset[i:(i+look_back), :]` - двоеточие вместо числа

Что означает это число или двоеточие после запятой? Как понимать такой список?

Аналогичный вопрос по строке `append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего `dataset` это объект типа `numpy.ndarray`.

Пример:

```
In [41]: import numpy as np

In [42]: dataset = np.arange(20).reshape(5,4)

In [43]: dataset
Out[43]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

вернуть значения второго (начиная с `0`) столбца:

```
In [44]: dataset[:, 2]
Out[44]: array([ 2,  6, 10, 14, 18])
```

вернуть 2D массив значений строки 1-3, столбцы 2-4:

```
In [45]: dataset[1:3, 2:4]
Out[45]:
array([[ 6,  7],
       [10, 11]])
```

второй столбец (двоеточие обозначает - все значения по данной оси (строки)) в виде 2D массива (размерностью 5x1)

```
In [46]: dataset[:, [2]]
Out[46]:
array([[ 2],
       [ 6],
       [10],
       [14],
       [18]])

In [47]: type(dataset)
Out[47]: numpy.ndarray
```

[Документация по индексированию в Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: MaxU, спасибо! Все стало понятно. Запускаю весь код. Выдает ошибку "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" с указанием на строку a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]. NumPy импортирован. Суть ошибки понятна, но куда копать, никто не скажет? По идее то код рабочий, если такая запись много где используется.

Comment: @Артур, я не могу воспроизвести данную ошибку - при целых `i` и `loop_back` - все работает правильно...

Comment: Понял. Буду копать у себя. Еще раз спасибо!